# Plotting vector field in polar coordinates

Tags: plotting

Is there an easy way(other than painfully decomposing into Cartesian components) to plot a vector field in polar coordinates? Basically I have a vector function $\vec V (r,\phi,z)$. How do I plot it ?

Comment: Can you provide some basic code? The form of the function. Preferably in a way that would be easy to cope and paste it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CoordinateTransform` to transform between different coordinate systems. Beware that you might have to use the *differential* of certain coordinate transformation in order to transform the vector components of the vector field appropriately

```
Φ = {x, y, z} \[Function] Evaluate[CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Cylindrical", {x, y, z}]];
Ψ = {r, ϕ, z} \[Function] Evaluate[CoordinateTransform["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", {r, ϕ, z}]];
DΨ = {r, ϕ, z} \[Function] Evaluate[D[Ψ[r, ϕ, z], {{r, ϕ, z}, 1}]];
```

Mathematically, this is

$$ \varPhi \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to {[0,\infty[} \times {]-\pi,\pi[} \times \mathbb{R}, \quad \varPhi(x,y,z) = \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arctan(x,y),z \right)$$

and

$$ \varPsi \colon {[0,\infty[} \times {]-\pi,\pi[} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3, \quad \varPsi(r ,\varphi,z) = \left(r \,\cos(\varphi),r \, \sin(\varphi),z \right)$$

Here is a vector field `V` in cylindrical coordinates and its transformation into cartesian coordinates.

```
V = {r, ϕ, z} \[Function] {r, 1, 3};
F = {x, y, z} \[Function] Evaluate[(DΨ @@ Φ[x, y, z]).V @@ Φ[x, y, z]];
```

In polar coordinates, `V` has to be interpreted as a mapping with values in the tangent bundle of ${[0,\infty[} \times {]-\pi,\pi[} \times \mathbb{R}$:

$$V \colon  {[0,\infty[} \times {]-\pi,\pi[} \times \mathbb{R} \to T({[0,\infty[} \times {]-\pi,\pi[} \times \mathbb{R}), \quad V(r,\varphi,z)  = \left(r \tfrac{\partial}{\partial r} + \tfrac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} + 3\, \tfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \right) \Big|_{(r,\varphi,z)}.$$

It has to be transformed like this:

$$F(x,y,z) = D\varPsi(\varPhi(x,y,z)) \cdot V(\varPhi(x,y,z)).$$

And this is the plot:

```
R = Pi;
VectorPlot3D[
 F[x, y, z], {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}, {z, -R, R},
 VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0.02],
 VectorScale -> 0.15,
 VectorPoints -> 6
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I am an amateur at using mathematica. Can you please tell me what the function V is in the code above? I couldn't spot any explicit definition for it

Comment: @Lelouch ``V = Function[{r, ϕ, z},  {r, 1, 3}];``

Comment: Again, sorry for asking , can you explicitly write the function and domain in mathematical form. I haven't used coordinate transform before.

Comment: Your result is different from the one given by Conor in the answer below… which one is correct?

Comment: @xzczd Hmm. I am pretty sure that Conor's solution is wrong: I think so because in Conor's solution, the vector field $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}$ (which corresponds to in cylindrical coordinates `{0,1,0}`) seems to have magnitude independent of $r$ when "transformed" to Euclidean coordinates. But it should have magnitude equal to $r$, no?

Comment: Ah, I think the problem is about what is meant by "a vector field in certain coordinates". That can mean three things: (i)  only the arguments of the vector field expression are expressed in different coordinates, (ii) the compontents of the vector field expression are in terms of the coordinate vector fields, or (iii) both. The latter is IMHO the only reasonable way to interpret "a vector field in certain coordinates". But I realize that this might not be what OP asked for or what `TransformedField` is supposed to do (if I am not mistaken, it addresses the case (i)).

Comment: Lesson to learn: Always give domain and codomain for all mappings to reduce ambiguity. And for vector fields in coordinates, also give the moving frame.

Comment: I think this is relevant?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192851/1871

Comment: @xzczd _That_ explains a lot. So `TransformedField` does not express the transformed vector field  with respect to the coordinate vector fields. While this explains the deviation between Conor's and my code, it is just not logical. (It is convenient for a couple of things, but it is just not logical.)

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica needs a coordinate-system option in `VectorPlot`.

For now a nice way to plot non-Cartesian fields is to use `TransformedField` which handles scalar, vector and even tensor fields.

Consider the cylindrical field used above.

```
{r, 1, 3}
```

we can very cleanly and without any thinking turn this into its Cartesian representation:

```
TransformedField["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", 

                {r, 1, 3}

              , {r, \[Phi], \[Zeta]} -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

and then plot it (like above)

```
VectorPlot3D[{x - y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y + x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], 3}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {z, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0.02], VectorScale -> 0.15, VectorPoints -> 6]
```

[image]

The coordinate-system option in `Div`, `Grad`, `Laplacian` etc. is excellent and it would be nice if this was incorporated into `VectorPlot`:

[image]