# TransformedField on Tensor

Tags: physics, coordinate-transformation

I was trying to use the TransformedField function to Transform the Metric Tensor $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ into Spherical coordinates. So i use:

```
TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", IdentityMatrix[3], {x, y, z} -> {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}]
```

Where i expect to get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & r^2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & r^2 \sin ^2(\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

But instead i obtain this:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Which is not what i expected from the Transformation of a Tensor. I am pretty sure i am doing something wrong here or something that is not supposed to be done like that but i can't quite put my finger on it. The Documentation doesn't Realy Mention how it Transforms Tensors just that it does.
Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: `TransformedField` transtorms in orthonormal bases, which is not the convention of differential geometry. There exist several related posts in this site e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192851/1871

Comment: @xzczd ah ok i didnt think about this posibility. So basically the difference is that in Diff Geo which is used in GR we dont use Orthonomal Bases for the Transformation Matrices?

Comment: Yes. BTW you can find even more related posts in math.SE  e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3742242/58219

Comment: @xzczd thanks that is realy interesting, tho i do get a bit confused as to why the unit vectors in the duals space are derivatives.

Comment: Do you mean you're confused by the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ denoting basis vectors? If so, it's because this notation is convenient, the calculation rule of the basis vectors is the same as that of partial derivative. (You may want to read [_The Poor Man’s Introduction to Tensors_](https://justincfeng.github.io/Tensors_Poor_Man.pdf). )

Comment: @xzczd Yeah i am confused about that as in the short introduction to Differential Geometry in my GR lecture, we never introduced this notation. Also thanks for that link i think thats gonna be very helpful

Answer (score 6):

Maybe we need to use `Grad` to calculate the Gram matrix

```
CoordinateTransform[  
 "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, θ, ϕ}]
Transpose[Grad[%, {r, θ, ϕ}]] . 
  Grad[%, {r, θ, ϕ}] // Simplify
```

> `{{1, 0, 0}, {0, r^2, 0}, {0, 0, r^2 Sin[θ]^2}}`