# How would you write a electric field in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: vector, vector-calculus, coordinate

I am new to Mathematica and I am trying to automate the process of finding electric and magnetic fields for TE and TM modes in a cylindrical superconducting cavity. I could not find documentation through which I can define a vector field.

Comment: A vector field should be just a list of functions. So, for instance, `f[x_, y_] = {-y, x}` would correspond to the vector field $r \hat{\phi}$, where the two elements of the list are the Cartesian components written in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Have a look at:" https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173081/plotting-vector-field-in-polar-coordinates". This is for spherical coordinates, but cylindrical coordinates are simpler.